# Copy entire folder structure to Resources subdir

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In Xcode there are the `Copy Files` Build Phases that let you copy files to a specified directory in the app bundle, but I need to copy an entire folder structure to `Resources/SubDir`.

Is there a way to do this *the right* way?

If not I've thought of just adding it as a ZIP and unpacking it to `Application Support` on launch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add folders by reference (represented by a blue icon), they'll keep the hierarchy, but the problem is making Xcode recognize there have been changes in the referenced directories. Take a look at [this blog post](http://majicjungle.com/blog/123/) which explains how to do it.

Comment: The contents of the folder don't change, so its just fine without a script

Answer (score 1):

When you drag the folder into Xcode, pick the option that reads *Create Folder References for any added folders*.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a run script build phase to create your directory structure.